# How would I got about parsing a php variable with this string stored in it?

Tags: php, parsing

I'm new to php and am trying to parse a string I'm getting. The string is the result of a bash script I'm running, and I'm storing the output into a php variable. Here is the output I'm getting:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step
[
  {
    "image_id": "mahomes1",
    "mean_score_prediction": 6.3682564571499825
  },
  {
    "image_id": "mahomes2",
    "mean_score_prediction": 6.7501190304756165
  },
  {
    "image_id": "mahomes3",
    "mean_score_prediction": 6.3136263862252235
  }, 
]
```

How would I go about parsing this string so that I can create a dictionary that stores the `"image_id"` value with the `"mean_score_prediction"` value?

Comment: How is this represented? Like `$string = '1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step [ ... ]'`?

Comment: Supress stderr or use some silencing option for the progressbar part of that scripts´ output.

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes, that's exactly how it's represented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is almost valid JSON, other than the beginning text and the comma between the final `}` and closing `]`. By cleaning those issues up, you can then use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on it to get a dictionary as an array of objects (or arrays, dependent on your preference):

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/^[^\v]+/', '/,(\s+\])/'), array('', '$1'), $string);
$dict = json_decode($string);
print_r($dict);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object (
    [image_id] => mahomes1
    [mean_score_prediction] => 6.36825645715 
  )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
    [image_id] => mahomes2
    [mean_score_prediction] => 6.7501190304756
  )
  [2] => stdClass Object (
    [image_id] => mahomes3
    [mean_score_prediction] => 6.3136263862252
  ) 
)
```

To get an array of arrays, call `json_decode` with a second parameter of `true` i.e.

```
$dict = json_decode($string, true);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vRnS9)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the response. This is exactly what I was looking for. Could you explain how that cleanup line works? The preg_replace function in specific.

Comment: @W.Verhulst `preg_replace` is a regexp replace. I've given it an array of patterns and replacements. The first pattern looks for all the characters from the start of the string up to the first vertical whitespace character (`\v`), that is replaced with an empty string `''`. The second pattern looks for a comma, followed by whitespace only then a closing `]`. That is replaced with just the whitespace and the `]`. If you go to my demo and `echo $string;` after the `preg_replace` statement you'll see what effect it has. [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)